# tipsy tooltip with ajax

Tags: jquery, tipsy

I m using tipsy tool tip with asp.net mvc. i want to get the details about image from database on mouseover and show the result in formatted html in tooltip. anyone have example how to do this thing with ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to suggest another jquery tooltip plugin - qTip2

It's indeed a very nice and easy to use plugin, for your question. You can do something like this:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
  content: {
  text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
  ajax: {
     url: '/path/to/file', // URL to the local file
     type: 'GET', // POST or GET
     data: {} // Data to pass along with your request
  }
}});
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: it work but having issue in the position of of qTip, any idea? i want it on the top left.

Comment: the position is totally customizable, see this： http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/position/